# When using a VPN (for anonymity) can other computers "see me"?

Tags: vpn, firewall

Just as I connected to the VPN, ipredator, allshare (sharing server from samsung, so tv can access stuff on computer), came up with a warning about azereus was trying to access my stuff. I don't have azereus on my computer, was that some random other guy's computer on the same net?

Thanks!

Comment: I can guarantee you that you actually do have azereus installed on your computer because it wasn't because your computer is connected to "some random guy's computer" because of the VPN. Even if "some random guy's computer" was connected firewall software on YOUR computer wouldn't altert you to network activity on the "some random guy's computer"

Comment: Hmm, I only use utorrent. It was not the firewall that alerted me. It was the allshare server, because I have to grant access. Like I did with my tv. I don't have azereus installed.

Comment: Well somebody with access to your computer installed it because thats the **only way** you would get the altert.  Your immpossible alternative theory is well **not possible.**

Comment: @Ramhound ok, thanks. I just assumed this was possible, because when using the university vpn i can print from to the school and I can access the uni server space.

Comment: You can access the printer and the server space based on the design of the VPN network.  But you wouldn't get a prompt to approve network access because "some random guy's computer" launched the some random program.  Despite what you think you actually have that program installed on your computer and its likely actually running.

Comment: Don't discount the possibility that the Samsung software was guessing the name and getting it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, other computers can see you when connected to a VPN.

A VPN does not hide your computer in any way - it encrypts the *data* from your computer to the remote network.  VPNs are typically used to create a secure tunnel through the Internet from your PC to the remote network, so that none of the hops in between can see the traffic.

The reality is *more* computers can "see" your computer, as you are now connected to two networks: your personal LAN and the university LAN.